# MySQL count time between each in/out and show total

Tags: mysql

I am having an issue with my time clock query. Basically users clock in/out several times per day (can clock in/out unlimited times per day), and it is counting the time between the first clock in and last clock out and I need it to count time between each in out and add up to provide result.

```
SELECT 
    user,
    '2020-01-01' as date,
    'Total Hours for Week:' as WeekDay,
    SUM(Minutes) as Minutes
    FROM (SELECT 
            tc.user,
            DATE(tc.timeinout) as date,
            CASE 
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=0 THEN 'Monday' 
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=1 THEN 'Tuesday'
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=2 THEN 'Wednesday'
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=3 THEN 'Thursday'
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=4 THEN 'Friday'
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=5 THEN 'Saturday'
                WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=6 THEN 'Sunday' END AS WeekDay,
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,tcmin.min,tcmax.max) AS Minutes
        FROM timeclock AS tc
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                    user,
                    MIN(timeinout) as min
                  FROM timeclock
                  GROUP BY user,DATE(timeinout)) as tcmin
            ON (tcmin.user=tc.user AND DATE(tcmin.min)=DATE(tc.timeinout))
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                    user,
                    MAX(timeinout) as max
                  FROM timeclock
                  GROUP BY user,DATE(timeinout)) as tcmax
            ON (tcmax.user=tc.user AND DATE(tcmax.max)=DATE(tc.timeinout))
        WHERE 
           tc.timeinout>= :startdate
            AND tc.timeinout< :enddate
            AND tc.user= :user
        GROUP BY tc.user,DATE(tc.timeinout)
        ORDER BY date ASC) AS Total
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    tc.user,
    DATE(tc.timeinout) as date,
    CASE 
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=0 THEN 'Monday' 
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=1 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=2 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=3 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=4 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=5 THEN 'Saturday'
        WHEN WEEKDAY(tc.timeinout)=6 THEN 'Sunday' END AS WeekDay,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,tcmin.min,tcmax.max) AS Minutes
    FROM timeclock AS tc
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            user,
            MIN(timeinout) as min
          FROM timeclock
          GROUP BY user,DATE(timeinout)) as tcmin
    ON (tcmin.user=tc.user AND DATE(tcmin.min)=DATE(tc.timeinout))
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            user,
            MAX(timeinout) as max
          FROM timeclock
          GROUP BY user,DATE(timeinout)) as tcmax
    ON (tcmax.user=tc.user AND DATE(tcmax.max)=DATE(tc.timeinout))
    WHERE 
    tc.timeinout>= :startdate
    AND tc.timeinout< :enddate
    AND tc.user= :user
    GROUP BY tc.user,DATE(tc.timeinout)
    ORDER BY date ASC
```

---

```
user   min                   max                   WeekDay     Minutes
----   -------------------   -------------------   ---------   -------
1      2015-07-27 20:20:32   2015-07-27 20:29:25   Monday      8 
1      2015-07-28 20:32:04   2015-07-28 20:36:28   Tuesday     4 
1      2015-07-29 20:40:00   2015-07-29 20:45:39   Wednesday   5 
1      2015-07-30 20:20:32   2015-07-30 20:20:56   Thursday    0 
1      2015-07-31 20:29:25   2015-07-31 20:32:04   Friday      2 
1      2015-08-01 20:36:28   2015-08-01 20:40:00   Saturday    3 
1      2015-08-02 20:20:32   2015-08-02 20:40:00   Sunday      19
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the question?

If you need to add up the last column, there two ways:

```
SELECT ... SUM(minutes) ...
    FROM (
          your query
         ) x
    GROUP BY ...
```

or...

```
GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP
```

Add `WITH ROLLUP` to your query and see if that is enough.